# How to search a keyword and store rest of the content with it in a variable using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a .properties file where the environment details are written like this:-

```
DEVOPS_app=app1,app2
DEVOPS_bat=bat1,bat2
```

I want my code to read this file to search for a particular environment (For Ex - "DEVOPS" here) and save all the content after "=" in a list. Here for example list_app will contain `app1` and `app2` and `list_bat` will contact `bat1` and `bat2`.

I am new to python so need someone's help here.

Thanks.

Comment: learn split function of a string

Comment: Did you bother trying anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

This code can help

```
out_list = []
req_word = "DEVOPS"
f = open("Propertiesfile.properties",'r')
for i in f.readlines():
    if(i.split("=")[0] == req_words"):
        out_list.append(i.split("=")[1:])
```